# Como testar a camada de Service em uma aplicação web service, utilizando mockito e junit

Tags: java, web-service, testes, junit, mockito

Tenho uma classe de serviços que receberá uma injeção de dependência de um objeto responsável pela camada de persistência.
Nesta classe de serviço está todos os meus métodos que responderão a chamada REST do web service.

O problema é:

Eu precisaria testar a classe de serviço, chamando os path's do web service REST, porém precisaria mockar a injeção de dependência da parte de persistência, pois neste momento só quero testar a camada de serviço.
Tudo isto utilizando junit e mockito, no máximo utilizando algo como o spring. Gostaria de saber dos colegas se isto é possível? Se sim, uma ideia do que devo fazer?

Abaixo um exemplo:

```java
@Path("/servico") 
public class Servico() {

    Persistencia persistencia;

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response get(long id) {
        Entidade entidade = persistencia.get(id);
        return Response.ok().entity(entidade).build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testes unitários são úteis apenas para testar a lógica de uma classe ou método.
Neste caso você têm um JAX-RS endpoint apenas, não há nenhuma lógica ai, e nem é aconselhavel ter, essa camada especificamente deve tratar apenas casos referentes ao REST. Não existe o "porque" de se testar Frameworks ou lib de terceiros em seus projetos, eles já devem estar testados.

Dito isso, se você precisar realmente achar necessário, teste de integração é o caminho. Porém para testar tudo isso você tem que fazer o deploy dentro de um container, inevitavelmente, oque aumenta em muito a complexidade dos testes.

Eu aconselho dois frameworks:

1. [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/)
2. [Rest assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/)

O segundo é especifico para testes para endpoints REST, já o primeiro é um Framework muito mais completo, Capaz de criar "micro deploys", a partir dae você pode efetuar testes mais próximos do ambiente de produção. Cada um tem suas particularidades de ultilização(Oque ficaria fora de escopo da pergunta).

Resumidamente: Se voce quiser testar o serviço REST funcionando mesmo, só com teste de integração em um container, claro.
Caso precise de um simples teste unitário, Mockito seria útil para mock da sua classe `Persistencia` pra dai então você testar `public Response get(long id)`.

Comment: Obrigado Josué Eduardo pela explicação e pelas dicas de frameworks, vou dar uma olhada neles.

Answer (score 0):

Olhe, há uma extensão de código aberto para JUnit que serve para testar APIs HTTP/REST:

http://developer.eclipsesource.com/restfuse/

Answer (score 0):

Usa o MockMVC do Spring, com ele você consegue testar seus endpoints REST, é interessante que com ele você consegue receber o JSON no retorno.

Nem precisa subir o servidor, esse framework faz a abstração disso e simula a camada de serialização e deserialização.

Estou no celular agora, da uns pesquisada sobre ele, se tiver dúvidas eu posso te mandar uns exemplos bem simples amanhã.

Se precisar é só chamar.

Abraços